# Getting "'gcc' failed with exit status 1" when trying to install Mecab with PyPy docker image

Tags: docker, pypy, mecab

My Docker image builds just fine when trying to install 3rd party package Mecab (https://pypi.org/project/mecab/) with CPython using image tag `python:3.8-slim`, but it fails with PyPy.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM pypy:3-7

RUN pypy -m ensurepip --default-pip

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV FLASK_APP "main.py"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install Mecab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install swig mecab libmecab-dev mecab-ipadic-utf8 git make curl xz-utils file sudo

# Set up Mecab
RUN git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/neologd/mecab-ipadic-neologd.git
RUN echo yes | mecab-ipadic-neologd/bin/install-mecab-ipadic-neologd -n -a

COPY Pip* /app/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install pipenv && \
    pipenv install --dev --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile

ADD . /app
```

And the full error output:

```
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 253, in install
[InstallError]:       site_packages=state.site_packages
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2063, in do_install
[InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1312, in do_init
[InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 900, in do_install_dependencies
[InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 796, in batch_install
[InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[InstallError]:   File "/opt/pypy/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 703, in _cleanup_procs
[InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting mecab-python3==0.996.5
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached mecab-python3-0.996.5.tar.gz (65 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for mecab-python3 (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for mecab-python3 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    command: /opt/pypy/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-9i8vw475
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Complete output (59 lines):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   copying src/MeCab/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Extension build configuration adjusted:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    libraries    = ['mecab', 'stdc++']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    swig_opts    = ['-O', '-builtin', '-c++', '-py3', '-I/usr/include']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   building 'MeCab._MeCab' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   swigging src/MeCab/MeCab.i to src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   swig -python -O -builtin -c++ -py3 -I/usr/include -o src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp src/MeCab/MeCab.i
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   /usr/include/mecab.h:136: Warning 302: Identifier 'surface' redefined by %extend (ignored),
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab.i:74: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'surface'.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   /usr/include/mecab.h:848: Warning 302: Identifier 'set_sentence' redefined by %extend (ignored),
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab.i:105: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'set_sentence'.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy/include -c src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.o -Wno-unused-variable
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void SwigPyBuiltin_SetMetaType(PyTypeObject*, PyTypeObject*)’:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:3444:11: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘ob_base’; did you mean ‘tp_base’?
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        type->ob_base.ob_base.ob_type = metatype;
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:              ^~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:              tp_base
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: At global scope:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8464:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8697:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8978:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9223:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9445:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9681:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:    ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit__MeCab()’:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:10401:16: error: ‘PyDescr_NewGetSet’ was not declared in this scope
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      this_descr = PyDescr_NewGetSet(SwigPyObject_type(), &this_getset_def);
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:10401:16: note: suggested alternative: ‘PyDescrObject’
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      this_descr = PyDescr_NewGetSet(SwigPyObject_type(), &this_getset_def);
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                   PyDescrObject
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py clean for mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Installing collected packages: mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Running setup.py install for mecab-python3: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Running setup.py install for mecab-python3: finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      command: /opt/pypy/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-784d25jp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/pypy/include/mecab-python3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Complete output (60 lines):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying src/MeCab/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     copying src/MeCab/MeCab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     Extension build configuration adjusted:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      library_dirs = ['/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      libraries    = ['mecab', 'stdc++']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      swig_opts    = ['-O', '-builtin', '-c++', '-py3', '-I/usr/include']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     building 'MeCab._MeCab' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     swigging src/MeCab/MeCab.i to src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     swig -python -O -builtin -c++ -py3 -I/usr/include -o src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp src/MeCab/MeCab.i
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     /usr/include/mecab.h:136: Warning 302: Identifier 'surface' redefined by %extend (ignored),
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab.i:74: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'surface'.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     /usr/include/mecab.h:848: Warning 302: Identifier 'set_sentence' redefined by %extend (ignored),
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab.i:105: Warning 302: %extend definition of 'set_sentence'.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/MeCab
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/opt/pypy/include -c src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.o -Wno-unused-variable
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function ‘void SwigPyBuiltin_SetMetaType(PyTypeObject*, PyTypeObject*)’:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:3444:11: error: ‘PyTypeObject’ {aka ‘struct _typeobject’} has no member named ‘ob_base’; did you mean ‘tp_base’?
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:          type->ob_base.ob_base.ob_type = metatype;
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                ^~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                tp_base
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: At global scope:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8464:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8697:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:8978:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9223:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9445:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:9681:1: error: too many initializers for ‘PyHeapTypeObject’ {aka ‘_heaptypeobject’}
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      };
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:      ^
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* PyInit__MeCab()’:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:10401:16: error: ‘PyDescr_NewGetSet’ was not declared in this scope
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        this_descr = PyDescr_NewGetSet(SwigPyObject_type(), &this_getset_def);
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     src/MeCab/MeCab_wrap.cpp:10401:16: note: suggested alternative: ‘PyDescrObject’
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:        this_descr = PyDescr_NewGetSet(SwigPyObject_type(), &this_getset_def);
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:                     PyDescrObject
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:     ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /opt/pypy/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7gu0in6y/mecab-python3_30c04743845644dab48b7bc8db7a8877/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-784d25jp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/pypy/include/mecab-python3 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Couldn't install package: mecab-python3
 Package installation failed...
```

I tried adding `gcc` to the installation but it did not solve the problem. Is Mecab not compatible with PyPy?

Comment: What version of swig are you using?

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I am also installing swig, updated the question. The version shows "swig3.0": `Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 swig3.0 amd64 3.0.12-2 [1397 kB]`

Comment: Can you use swig4.0.2? Your version was released in 2017, before SWIG was fixed for PyPy.

Comment: @mattip Thanks. It looks like that version is only available via building from source code...is that right?

Comment: Seems like it, https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=swig4.0 lists swig4 only in unstable (sid) and testing (bullseye)

Comment: But conda has it, so you could use pypy in a conda environment, which might get you mecab already built

Answer (score 0):

Since very few projects upload binary wheels for PyPy, the easiest way to get binary packages for PyPy is to use conda

```
conda create -n pypy37  pypy python=3.7
conda activate pypy37
conda install mecab  # gets version 0.996
```

Comment: Not all packages that are available via pip (on Pypi) are available with conda. Even conda forge.